# Geoprocessing with ArcGIS Server 10.0 - %scratchworkspace%

Tags: arcgis-server, arcpy, geoprocessing

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Key_concepts_for_geoprocessing_services/002v00000002000000/

I'm trying to have a new GP Service arcpy.AddMessage() the scratchworkspace that is created on that run.  I keep getting a invalid syntax error.

But real aim is to write to this scratchworkspace but the %scratchworkspace%/ doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
line = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage(line)
try:
    arcpy.AddMessage(str(%scratchworkspace%))
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(traceback.format_exc())
```

This is a gp service published through the arcmap process, I've opened and run the tool layer once already and the Tool is creating the scratchworkspace in arcgisjobs directory

arcgisjobs\geoprocessing\gpservicetest_gpserver\jf93e76ce2f0f4967b7b9028c384b19f8\scratch

So how do I get a hold of this in python to write to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combing through this guys code (thanks for the link on the other question!) [Setting Output Parameter in ArcPy for Server Tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18464/setting-output-parameter-in-arcpy-for-server-tool)

yielded this and it WORKED!

"%SCRATCHWORKSPACE%\\outPoint.shp"

as an output parameter to a arcpy.CopyFeatures_management call.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will need to use arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace instead of %scratchworkspace%.

This [blog posting](http://blogs.esri.com/dev/blogs/geoprocessing/archive/2011/06/24/exportmodeltopy.aspx) makes mention of %scratchworkspace% only being applicable to ModelBuilder and this [Help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000003000000) provides more details about arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace.

Answer (score 0):

`%scratchworkspace%` is not resolved by the Python script. Instead it is set when passed as a tool input through ArcGIS Desktop or Server.

I.E. if you have a tool parameter, say `scratch_dir` and set it to `%scratchworkspace%` within the ArcGIS environment before you run the tool, accessing `scratch_dir` would give you the directory path (e.g. *arcgisjobs\etc...*).

So, modifying your code above:

```py
line = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.AddMessage(line)
scratch_dir = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
try:
    arcpy.env.workspace = scratch_dir
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(traceback.format_exc())
```